# How does logistic regression work with p>n?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic

Just followed a machine learning example and programmed a gradient decent maximizaation to read in a 64X64X3 image vector to predict whether it was a cat or not.  The model had a parameter for every pixel*color so 12288 parameters were optimized.  It worked, a vector of parameter estimates were obtained and predictions were obtained and worked pretty well (prediction accuracy good).  How did this work, when I only had 200 samples, so p >>n. I thought we could not estimate parameters in regression when p

Comment: prediction accuracy for the training set or the test set?

Comment: n=200 training samples... m=50 test set.  Accuracy was decent on the test set.

Comment: Rather depends what was being maximized (or descended - gotta make your mind up :-)

Comment: The cost function for a logistic regression.